# How to create chart application in iphone

Tags: iphone, charts

I'm assigned with new task for creating chart application in iphone like.,(BarChart,PieChart,etc..,).But,i have no idea for chart application in iphone.Please anyone help me out to guide me to start chart application in iphone.If any of the frameworks or API used for this kind of chart application means please explain that also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a shot to:
[Core-Plot Framework](https://github.com/core-plot)

To get it working, read [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application).
You can also see the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070993/core-plot-iphone-animation-examples) SO question.
For a little bar-chart tutorial [go here](http://bertmcdowell.com/?page_id=606).

There is also:
[s7graphview](https://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/) less features but It's an option.

If you can rely on the web, although it's a far from optimal solution, you can embed a UIWebView in your application, and use the [Google Graph Visualization API](https://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/visualization/documentation/) or you can use a UIWebView with an HTML5 graph library lake [rgraph](https://www.rgraph.net/). Look here for a [jQuery](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/) based solution. Filament Group made also [this one](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/).

At the and some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple (Accelerometer Graph).

Comment: Thank You microspino...Thanks for your sample application in this regard.Which is very much useful for me to start my application.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used Cocoa "native" charting library is [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). Whilst I've yet to personally use it, it seems to be [quite popular](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot) and is under active development.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, but next time please use the search function first:
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

---

### [Cocoa Graphing/Plotting Framework that Works on iPhoneOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263472/cocoa-graphing-plotting-framework-that-works-on-iphoneos)

Answer (score 0):

A popular one is core plot. http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/